# The folder "Images.xcassets" doesn't exist

Tags: ios, xcode

When I open the project file in the latest xcode version, I get the error "The folder "Images.xcassets" doesn't exist" in two popups. I have to click OK multiple times to make the popups disappear. I haven't done anything to remove such folders. Does anyone have an idea why I might be getting them?

**Update:**

I see it in finder and in my project explorer too. The problem still persists.
[image]

Comment: Try to explore the project directory with the Finder and see if the folder Images.xcassets does exist. If yes, drag and drop it into Xcode. If not it might has been deleted, in this case you have yo create a new assets folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have probably set your launch images to be extracted from an asset catalog (which is 'images.xcassets' by default). If you don't want to use asset catalogs, go to your application settings and select 'don't use asset catalogs', but, if you do (I recommend you do use asset catalogs for App Icons and Launch Images), click 'create asset catalog'. If that option isn't available, right click on your project, select 'New File', go to 'Resource', and select Asset Catalog.

Comment: It's not the case. I see "The folder “Images.xcassets” doesn’t exist." alert jumping twise on the screen. I do use the assets all the time.
I added a framework and now I see this alert. Probably, something's broken in the project settings.

Comment: @Pavel have you fixed your problem, I experience the same thing

Comment: @PaulBrewczynski I do not remember even. I think the folder has be in a specific place in the project tree. Since that time I never move it.

Answer (score 7):

I used the hotkey combinations for Cleaning the Project and Cleaning the Build Folder. Building again after this did the trick. The problem came up after merging too Git Repository Branches of our Project and trying to build.

Clean Build Folder:

<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Command</kbd> + K

Clean Project:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + K

Answer (score 2):

I solved a similar issue by doing this:

1. Remove the `Images.xcassets` folder from your project.
2. Close Xcode and open `.xcodeproj` using VSCode or similar tool.

In VSCode, find every reference to `Images.xcassets` and remove the line. Save the file and open Xcode. Then add `Images.xcassets` back to your project.

Answer (score 1):

I have been plagued by this problem over the past month or two. It didn't hurt anything – it was just annoying. The problem exhibited itself in both Xcode's 6.4 and 7.

I finally fixed it today by inserting the following lines into our project's info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict/>
<key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
<dict/>
```

Actually what I did was from the project settings' General pane under App Icons and Launch Images, I changed the App Icons Source from my asset catalog to "Don't use asset catalogs" and then changed it back to "Use Asset Catalog". Xcode then modified my asset catalog by inserting a 2nd entry for AppIcon, but I just rolled that change back using my git client. The change to the info.plist (shown above) I left in place, and this solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Exact situation happened for me.
The thing is that , i have added second target unknowingly.
Deleting all the files related to that second target , solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the 'App icons source' and 'Launch Images Source' to 'Don't use asset catalogs', switch to other file then switch back, the popups will disappear.
2. Reset the 'App icons source' and 'Launch Images Source'.

Answer (score -2):

Add Image. Imageset folder in your project, in Assets.xcassets director.