# The folder "Images.xcassets" does not exist

Tags: ios, xcode, spritebuilder

I just added "Images.xcassets" in my SpriteBuilder project for app icons. Everything works fine, except, whenever I click on project icon in navigator it shows two dialog boxes with the message: **The folder "Images.xcassets" does not exist**.

Now I can see both in my Xcode project and in Finder that "Images.xcassets" does exist. Moreover, Xcode has no problem finding the assets when building the project. I also checked similar question asked in the page "[The folder "Images.xcassets" doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584572/the-folder-images-xcassets-doesnt-exist)" but none of the answers in the page solved the issue for me. Is this a bug in Xcode or is there any fix for the nagging dialog boxes, which appear apparently for no reason at all?